# RestSharp Deserialize a List in a List

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization, restsharp

i have some trouble getting this to work:

my xml looks like:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <CollectionProp>
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <name></name>
            </item>
        </CollectionProp>
    </item>
</root>
```

my class looks like:

```
public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<CollectionProp> CollectionProp { get; set; }
}
```

and another one:

```
public class CollectionProp
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

i also tried to wrap another class around CollectionProp

```
CollectionPropCollection : List<CollectionProp>
```

Also tried: CollectionPropCollection class with / or with a property "item" of type CollectionProp.

here's my execute statement:

```
var result = client.Execute<List<Item>>(request);
```

**EDIT Aug 19:**

ok, my post may not clearly pointed out my problem.
so now i think i broke down the problem to the following:

the XmlDeserializer has a problem to distinguish between the item under  and the item under

so the response has 2 items under  and each has 3 items under , my deserialized result has 8 objects. the first with values, the next 3 with properties set to null, the 4th with values and so on....

any idea how i can solve this in a way like : item under  needs to be parsed into objectA, item under , which is a child of item under root, needs to be parsed into objectB ?

Answer (score 1):

If the xml file is a serialized `Item` you can do this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item)); //or if you have a item variable item.GetType()
FileStream stream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
Item item = (Item) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
```

UPDATE

When it's a list of Items you just replace `typeof(Item)` with `typeof(List<Item>)` and you cast it to a `List<Item>`

Comment: that works, but does not solve my problem. itemList[0].CollectionProperty should List of objects too but is always null, so the sub-list is not deserialized

Comment: Hmm, I guess you serialized it using another method. You could either use that same serializer object as in the example only then with `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` and (de)serialize it that way. Are you sure that List isn't null before serialization? I also made a small lib to make it a bit easier, it can be found here http://www.xtudiocreatives.nl/xxmlserializer/

Comment: i'm getting my data from the restsharp response object. the data property of this object has the xml in a string. using the client.Execute<List<Item>>(response) i receive a list of "item" objects with a property "CollectionProps" of type List<CollectionProp> which is not null but only deserializes the first entry, even if there are more

Comment: I can recommend only 1 thing at the moment: Download RestSharp v 101.3. From the website: _FIXED: Some XML attributes not deserialized correctly when using classes that derive from List<T>_ http://restsharp.org/